filtering in folium based on two column values
I aim to utilize ipywidgets dropdowns and Folium to filter and visualize geodataframes. As an example, let's consider a geodataframe sourced from Natural Earth vectors, containing columns such as 'continent' and 'name'.
My objective is to create a user interface where users can first select a continent from a dropdown. Upon selection, another dropdown dynamically populates with the countries falling within that continent. Finally, when a country is chosen from the second dropdown, its location will be displayed on a Folium map.
I intend to save this interactive notebook as an HTML file.
Below is the code I've attempted so far based on the How do add drop down menu for the folium map?
import geopandas as gpd
import ipywidgets
from IPython.display import HTML, display
import folium


df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

df = df[['continent', 'geometry']]

out = ipywidgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})

w = ipywidgets.Dropdown(
    options=df['continent'].unique().tolist(),
    value=df['continent'].tolist()[0],
    description='Column:',
    disabled=False,
)


# Define a function to filter the dataframe
def filter_dataframe(name):
    return df[df['continent'] == name]


def on_dropdown_change(change):
    out.clear_output()
    df = filter_dataframe(w.value)
    with out: 
        display(df.explore(df.columns[0], cmap="Blues"))

w.observe(on_dropdown_change, names='value')
display(w)

with out:
    display(df.explore(df.columns[0], cmap="Blues"))

out


I do not have enough experience with ipywidgets. I'll preface this by saying that there may be better code out there, but based on the answers in SO, I have configured a dictionary with a continent selection and a list of countries associated with that continent. The handler in the first dropdown has the country list set by the continent selection result, the second dropdown extracts the dataframe by continent value and country value.
import geopandas as gpd
import ipywidgets
from IPython.display import HTML, display
import folium
import mapclassify

df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

continent_group = {}
continent_list = df.continent.unique()[:6]
continent_list.insert(0, 'all')

for c in continent_list:
    dff = df.query('continent == @c')
    continent_group[c] = dff['name'].tolist()

df = df[['continent', 'name', 'geometry']]

out = ipywidgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})

w = ipywidgets.Dropdown(
    options=continent_list,
    value=continent_list[0],
    description='Continet:',
    disabled=False,
)

c = ipywidgets.Dropdown(
    description='Counrty:',
    disabled=False,
)

def continent_update(x):
    country_list = continent_group[x]
    c.options = country_list

# Define a function to filter the dataframe
def filter_dataframe(continent_name, country_name):
  #print('country_name:', country_name)
  if country_name is None:
    return df[df['continent'] == continent_name]
  else:
    return df[(df['continent'] == continent_name) & (df['name'] == country_name)]


def dropdown_eventhandler1(change):
    print('w.value',w.value, 'c.value',c.value)
    continent_update(w.value)
    out.clear_output()
    df = filter_dataframe(w.value, None)
    with out: 
      display(df.explore(df.columns[0], cmap="Blues"))

def dropdown_eventhandler2(change):
    #continent_update(w.value)
    out.clear_output()
    df = filter_dataframe(w.value, c.value)
    with out: 
      display(df.explore(df.columns[1], cmap="Blues"))

w.observe(dropdown_eventhandler1, names='value')
c.observe(dropdown_eventhandler2, names='value')

display(w, c)

with out:
    display(df.explore(df.columns[0], cmap="Blues", legend=False))

out





Could we incorporate an 'All' option for both the Continent and Country dropdowns? This enhancement would allow users to visualize all countries within a selected continent when 'All' is chosen. For instance, if the continent 'Asia' and the country 'All' are selected, the Folium map should display all countries within Asia. However, if a specific country is chosen, the map should focus solely on that country.
Presently, all continents and countries are displayed under 'Oceania' in the continent dropdown, and users cannot select countries within Oceania.

I had tested all the other options except for Oceania, but that was the only one I had omitted to check. I added 'all' to the beginning of the continent list to fulfill your request. I tried to add 'all' to the initial value for the countries as well, but it didn't work.
